# Angular APP_BASE_HREF appends multiple times

Tags: angular, jboss, angular2-routing

I deploy my website on the url `https://www.example.com/suburl`.

To handle the deployed and the local state, I provide the base href dynamically, like so:

```js
@NgModule({
  providers: [
    {
      provide: APP_BASE_HREF,
      useValue: getBaseHrefUrl(),
    }
  ],

  // ...
})
export class AppModule {}

function getBaseHrefUrl(): string {
  if (environment.production) {
    return 'suburl/';
  }
  return '.';
}
```

This however results in `'suburl'` beeing appended twice to the url when routing - for example with the page `'home'`: `https://www.example.com/suburl/suburl`. This one does not work and no navigation is done.

When I turn on hash based routing, it shows the following url when navigating to `'home'`: `https://www.example.com/suburl#/suburl/home`. This one actually works, but the url is still malformed.

When I just set the `APP_BASE_HREF` to `'.'`, everything works as intended, but I don't understand why? Shouldn't the base href specify the part that is not changeable by Angular?

The whole thing is deployed on a JBoss Server if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 1):

It seems your Root url is https://www.example.com/suburl .

The router seems to be working fine as it looks like you're appending a /suburl/ value based on the intended environment that its in.
If you can imagine that your APP_BASE_HREF is using a relative path to the base URL I think this will make more sense.  By setting your base href to '.' you're actually telling Angular to not append anything and just point to your root.

I would consider deploying your site to https://www.example.com/

Comment: I dont have much knowledge in JBoss. What makes my /suburl a root url?